# JS Discord Bot "Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

"bot.js": https://hastebin.com/hujexulemo.js
"mute.js": https://hastebin.com/rewibeledo.js

When I try to run the code,
I get this error:

```
let mutedRole = guild.roles.get(r => r.name === " Muted ");
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
    at Timeout.bot.setInterval [as _onTimeout] (E:\DiscordBot\bot.js:40:35)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

The code that is relevant to this question (from your hastebin links) is these two lines:

```
let guild = bot.guilds.get(guildId);
let mutedRole = guild.roles.get(r => r.name === " Muted ");
```

The error you're getting comes from `guild.roles` in the 2nd line, where `guild` is `undefined`, which means there is no property `roles` on it. This can happen when `bot.guilds.get(guildId)` does not find a guild with id `guildId`.

To fix this, make sure your `guildId` is correct before calling `bot.guilds.get(guildId)`, or check that `guild` exists before the `let mutedRole = ...` line.

The docs for the `Map`'s `.get` function are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get).

**Note for confused Discord.js devs:**
The `.get` function is only *briefly* mentioned in the [`Collection.find(...)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.0.0/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) docs:

> Do not use this [`.find()`] to obtain an item by its ID. Instead, use collection.get(id). See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) for details.

This confused me for a while, so hopefully it helps others :)